# Why is webpack bundling extra files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I have created a simple [github repo](https://github.com/ihorbond/vue-cli-webpack) to reproduce my scenario.

I have 2 config files: dev.vue.config.js and prod.vue.config.js that are used depending on NODE_ENV value

For prod my webpack entry point is set as

```
configureWebpack: {
    entry: {
      activitySubmit: './src/as-setup.js'
    }
  }
```

and I also use SplitChunks plugin to bundle node_modules into vendors.js so I expect webpack to produce 2 files: *activitySubmit.js* and *vendors.js*

However I'm also getting 3rd file *app.js* which has contents of *src/main.js* but why ? I'm not specifying it as my entry point and no other file is importing anything from *main.js* so why is it getting bundled anyway ? I don't need it in prod.

Now, if I change the entry point to

```
configureWebpack: {
    entry: {
      app: './src/as-setup.js'
    }
  }
```

I get 2 files: *app.js* and *vendors.js*

and if I inspect *app.js* I can see that it now does not contain code from *src/main.js* (as expected).
I'm confused, please help explain the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question got answered on Vue Forum so I'm posting the answer here as well

Running

```
vue inspect --mode production
```

will show the Webpack configuration that Vue CLI is generating. It ends up with:

```
entry: {
  app: [
    './src/main.js'
  ],
  activitySubmit: './src/as-setup.js'
}
```

because as explained in [vue docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration), the configuration you provide in configureWebpack is merged using webpack-merge, so the default entry is still present.